# How to partially darken a background image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.darken {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: hidden;
    padding: 20%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), no-repeat center top / cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="darken" style="background-image: url("https://smorder.blob.core.windows.net/images/6/d9ffff37-79a2-44b2-aef4-6c8aadff1c6e");"></div>
```

But, it does not achieve what I want exactly. As I want to darken the left side of the image partially. I want to achieve something like this: http://prntscr.com/gj0hs8

Any ideas how to achieve this darkening effect?

Comment: Remove the image URL from your inline HTML and instead include it in your CSS after the comma . Currently as is, it doesn't know that your second background instruction is referring to the image. Sorry just on phone now so can't test.

Comment: @Adrian I'm originally using React, and I pass the image url inside the component. I just included the HTML and CSS snippet here. I though it is enough, as I need to apply some kind of CSS I believe to darken it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linear gradient is treated as a background image too.

You can use it as an overlay if set first while using multiple background-image.

Mind the start/stop value, direction and to set 2 different colors in order to draw a gradient *(tune provided example below to your needs)*.

A simple gradient always covers its container, no need to reset background-size to it

example below.

```css
.darken {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: hidden;
    padding: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="darken" style="
background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%) no-repeat center top ,  
    url(http://lorempixel.com/800/500/nightlife/7) 0 0 /cover ;">
test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a div as overlay and give this one the gradient and it should work

Comment: You don't even need that. You can have two backgrounds in the one CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might work

```css
.darken {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: hidden;
    padding: 20%;
 background-image: url("https://preview.ibb.co/fQxszF/security.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.overlay::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-230px, -60px) rotate(145deg);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 77%;
    height: 65%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="darken overlay"></div>
```

Include the class overlay in the div.

Appreciate if useful.